# jQuery odd even on nested list

Tags: php, jquery, list

**jQuery**:

```
$("li:even div").removeClass("odd even").addClass("odd");
$("li:odd div").removeClass("odd even").addClass("even");​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hashie5/vk6rZ/

As you can see in the fiddle, odd/even does not work properly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `li` elements does not have the same parent, that's why it won't work.

Comment: thanks I know, but how can I solve this?

Comment: I am not sure if you are want this. But have a look http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/vk6rZ/4/

Comment: @Joy was about to say that. Write your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at the `li:even>div` instead of `li:even div`

```
$("li:even>div").removeClass("odd even").addClass("odd");
$("li:odd>div").removeClass("odd even").addClass("even");
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/vk6rZ/4/

target immediate children (divs)

```
$("li:even > div").removeClass("odd even").addClass("odd");
$("li:odd > div").removeClass("odd even").addClass("even");​
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this: http://jsfiddle.net/hashie5/vk6rZ/

```
$("li:even > div").removeClass("odd even").addClass("odd");
$("li:odd > div").removeClass("odd even").addClass("even");
```